# Unable to backup on local with solr cloud 8.10 version. ClassNotFoundException for LocalFileSystemRepository

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I'm trying to back up locally a solr cloud collection as described in the [docs](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_10/making-and-restoring-backups.html#localfilesystemrepository), I added this to my solr.xml

```xml
<backup>
    <repository name="local_repo" class="org.apache.solr.core.backup.repository.LocalFileSytemRepository" default="true">
      <str name="location">/var/solr/backup_data</str>
    </repository>
</backup>
```

and tried to backup with

```sh
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=BACKUP&name=name&collection=name&location=/var/solr/data'
```

but I'm getting this error:

```json
{
    "responseHeader": {
        "status": 500,
        "QTime": 11
    },
    "error": {
        "metadata": [
            "error-class",
            "org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
            "root-error-class",
            "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException"
        ],
        "msg": "Error loading class 'org.apache.solr.core.backup.repository.LocalFileSytemRepository'",
        "trace": "org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading class 'org.apache.solr.core.backup.repository.LocalFileSytemRepository'\n\tat org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:554)\n\tat org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.newInstance(SolrResourceLoader.java:612)\n\tat org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.newInstance(SolrResourceLoader.java:607)\n\tat org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.newInstance(SolrResourceLoader.java:599)\n\tat org.apache.solr.core.backup.repository.BackupRepositoryFactory.newInstance(BackupRepositoryFactory.java:75)\n\tat org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.newBackupRepository(CoreContainer.java:282)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CollectionsHandler$CollectionOperation.lambda$static$33(CollectionsHandler.java:1115)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CollectionsHandler$CollectionOperation.execute(CollectionsHandler.java:1453)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CollectionsHandler.invokeAction(CollectionsHandler.java:285)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CollectionsHandler.handleRequestBody(CollectionsHandler.java:257)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:216)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.handleAdmin(HttpSolrCall.java:836)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.handleAdminRequest(HttpSolrCall.java:800)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:545)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:427)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:357)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:201)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:548)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:600)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1624)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1434)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:501)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1594)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1349)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:191)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.InetAccessHandler.handle(InetAccessHandler.java:177)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:146)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:322)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:763)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:400)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:645)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:392)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:277)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:338)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:315)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:173)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:409)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:883)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1034)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)\nCaused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.solr.core.backup.repository.LocalFileSytemRepository\n\tat java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)\n\tat java.base/java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(URLClassLoader.java:899)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)\n\tat org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:538)\n\t... 54 more\n",
        "code": 500
    }
}
```

I tried to copy everything from `/opt/solr/dist` to `/opt/solr/server/solr/lib/` and `/opt/solr/server/solr-webapp/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/` and restarting solr but no luck :(

What am I missing?

Comment: If you put every lib in these folders, I don't know, maybe it is expected to be in your [solr_home](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_10/taking-solr-to-production.html#solr-home-directory) directory. Anyway, you have better to define classpath(s) explicitly using [`lib` directives](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_10/libs.html#lib-directives-in-solrconfig) in `solrconfig.xml`. When a directive matches a directory, then resources can be resolved from it, and when it matches a .jar file, Solr plugins and their dependencies are resolved from it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in the example that you pulled from the docs for local_repo. The class name `LocalFileSytemRepository` should be `LocalFileSystemRepository`. This class is already in solr-core.jar and so you shouldn't have to do anything special to bring it into the lib. Just correct the solr.xml and reload and everything should start working.

The correct snippet should look like:

```xml
<backup>
    <repository name="local_repo" class="org.apache.solr.core.backup.repository.LocalFileSystemRepository" default="true">
      <str name="location">/var/solr/backup_data</str>
    </repository>
</backup>
```